# May I publish xml manifest file on our web site before pass the review?

Tags: office-js, office-store

We are publishing our app in office store and our web site.

We will update the app, may i publish xml manifest file on our web site before pass the review for update app?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because "Questions asking about the store's terms & conditions or seeking customer service are off-topic."

Answer (score -1):

your manifest will only be checked on the supported Office platforms as called for by the manifest. Publishing your manifest on your website will not interfere with the validation.